# How to access a row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

could you explain me please the difference between those two:

```
#1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

```
#2
for x in df['city']:
```

Should I always use or  `for index, row in df.iterrows():` while trying to access data in pandas:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
for x in df['city']:
```

Or in some cases specifying the column name like in the second example will me enough?

Thank you

Comment: with `iterrows` you can iterate over rows. With `for x in df['city']` you iterate over the values of the `'city'` column.

Comment: I don't get into your question? Do you want to access a single row or the whole row?

Comment: @timgeb Thank you!

Comment: @DejeneT. After reading your question, the answer to my question is clear =)

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to iterate than the ways you described. It all comes down to how simple your iteration is and the "efficiency" of it.
The second example way will be enough if you just want to iterate rows over a single column.

Also bare in mind, depending on the method of iteration, they return different dtypes. You can read about them all on pandas doc.

This is an interesting article explaining the different methods regarding performance https://medium.com/@rtjeannier/pandas-101-cont-9d061cb73bfc

Comment: Thank you! Reading the article :)

Comment: Could you please tell me if there is an alternative, a more efficient way than .iterrows() if I want to get only unique elements of a column? I mean cases when I would normally use set to avoid repetitions? Like:     for index, row in df.iterrows():
        df.add(row['oci']) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
            print(row['city'])
```

Explanation: It helps us to iterate over a data frame row-wise with row variable having values for each column of that row & 'index' having an index of that row. To access any value for that row, mention the column name as above

```
  for x in df['city']:
         print(x)
```

Explanation: It helps us to iterate over a Series df['city'] & not other columns in df.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!